# Is there any way to send directinput keys to an inactive window without activating it in python?

Tags: python, postmessage, directinput, ctype

- python 3.9.13 / A window : active / B window : inactive
  I want to send DirectInput keys to B window without activating it.
  But it doesn't work.

PostMessage - It sends keys to B window without activating B, but it uses VK.

ctype - It sends DirectInput keys, but it only works with active window.

I have no idea how I can handle this.